# i cant show my example blog in my blade use laravel6 and vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i want to do a test with `vuejs` and `laravel 6`,i `run npm install` and `npm run dev` and `npm run watch`, i created a `BlogPosts` component i add `<posts> </posts>` in my layouts i configure `app.js` but i saw nothing in layouts.

**layout(landing-page.blade.php)**

```
<div id="app">
<h1>example</h1>
            <posts></posts>
</div
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

**resources/js/components/BlogPosts.vue**

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('posts', require('./components/BlogPosts.vue').default);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

**BlogPosts.vue**

```
<template>
   <div>posts go here</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script tag with vue code is after the component you should not use `defer`

Instead:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```